# CFA or higher order factor model or SEM

Tags: r, factor-analysis, structural-equation-model

I have some questions regarding CFA and SEM.

I have developed a conceptual model and collected data for it.  Now I'm struggling with the actual analysis because I haven't study much statistics. So whats in this post is based on my few days reading.

Basically, I want to use R rather other software such as Mplus to do the modelling. This is because R requires me to model it step by step which means the learning will be magnified.

Initially I went down the wrong track of using EFA which I soon realised isn't needed because I already developed a model prior.

Now with CFA i'm trying to understand whether my conceptual model from below can be viewed as a third order factor model?

variables on the far left are the mediator variables(observed) of the manifest variables in the middle.

How should I go about doing this in R? I saw some CFA examples of second order three factor model but haven't seen one like mine where there are mediator variables.
Thanks in advance!
[image]

Comment: I think you might want to check out "OpenMx". It's a free and open-source software add-on for R. Personally I have not worked with it but from what I hear it seems like what would suit your needs.